# How to read request & response body inside apache HttpClient interceptor?

Tags: java, httpresponse, interceptor

I want to read request & response twice, one at the interceptor layer and another at the server/client layer respectively. Since the apache client interceptor doesn't give any next() method so I am unable to use any wrapper. So how can i read them twice.

Below is the code:

```java
// HttpRequestInterceptor
HttpRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void process(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Inside HttpRequestInterceptor");
        System.out.println("Request Headers-> ");
        Header[] allHeaders = httpRequest.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i = 0; i < allHeaders.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(allHeaders[i].getName());
        }

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }
};

HttpResponseInterceptor responseInterceptor = new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void process(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {

        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Inside HttpResponseInterceptor");
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

        System.out.println("Response Headers-> ");
        Header[] allHeaders = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i = 0; i < allHeaders.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(allHeaders[i].getName());
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
    }
};


CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().addInterceptorFirst(requestInterceptor).addInterceptorLast(responseInterceptor).build();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
//Setting the header to it
httpget.setHeader(new BasicHeader("sample-header", "My first header"));
httpget.setHeader(new BasicHeader("demo-header", "My second header"));
httpget.setHeader(new BasicHeader("test-header", "My third header"));

HttpResponse httpResponse;
try {
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

System.out.println("------------------------------");

System.out.println("Response after executing request");

// Can not read response since stream is closed---->

        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())); 
System.out.println("Response Headers after executing");
Header[] allHeaders = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();

for (Header header : allHeaders) {
    System.out.println(header.getName());
}
System.out.println("------------------------------");
```